# Can't get JSON using Volley Library on Android 2.3 device

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm using Volley library to get JSON. I have my Nexus 5, Nexus 7, running Android 4.4.4 and everything is fine. The emulator also gets JSON on Android 4.2.2 and 4.4. When I'm trying to get JSON using HTC Wildfire, which is rooted, running Android 2.3.7, it is trying to load JSON but then quits. The same with emulator running Android 2.3.

### My JSONObjectRequest method:

```
 private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
    showpDialog();
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                extractJSONArray(response.getJSONArray("Accommodation"), "accommodation");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // notifying list adapter about data changes
            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            hidepDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidepDialog();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

### Volley Error:

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

### Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @linkas - first find out the Error Response volley throwing, it would have been great help if we know the actual error.

Comment: [get what is the error Volley throwing you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19720081/2591002)

Comment: I have edited my question. Yes, it is full logcat.