# Handle OnErrorResponse Method - Volley

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-volley

I'm fetching data from a server in json format using volley. Everything works fine when connected to Wifi. But when user is connected to mobile data and especially if mobile data connection is slow OnErrorResponse method is called. I have put a Toast message in OnErrorResponse method. In some devices this toast message crashes with NullPointerException while in others it runs fine.

Also if I wait for a long time, and the results are not yet displayed then app crashes with outofmemory error. Please help me.

How to handle these problems efficiently?

Code:

```
private RequestQueue songQueue = songQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());



 private void getNewSongs() {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, newSongsUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            JSONObject artistObject = null;
            String artist = "";
            String albumID = "";
            String artistID = null;

            try {


                JSONObject songListObjects = response.getJSONObject("new_song");

                    if(songListObjects.has("data")){

                        JSONObject data = songListObjects.getJSONObject("data");

                        if(data.has("song_list")) {

                            JSONArray songList = data.getJSONArray("song_list");

                            for (int i=0;i<5;i++){

                                JSONObject songListObject = songList.getJSONObject(i);

                                if (songListObject.has("mid")) {

                                    Log.e("SongListObject has", "songmid");
                                    String songID = songListObject.getString("mid");
                                    String songTitle = songListObject.getString("name");
                                    long duration = songListObject.getLong("interval") * 1000;
                                    Log.e("Title:", songTitle);
                                    Log.e("Duration:", String.valueOf(duration));

                                    JSONObject albumObject  = songListObject.getJSONObject("album");

                                    if(albumObject.has("mid")){

                                        albumID = albumObject.getString("mid");


                                    }



                                    JSONArray artistArray = songListObject.getJSONArray("singer");

                                    for (int j = 0; j < artistArray.length(); j++) {

                                        artistObject = artistArray.getJSONObject(j);

                                        if (j == 0) {

                                            if (artistObject.has("name")) {


                                                Log.e("ArtistObject: ", "has name");

                                                artist = artistObject.getString("name");
                                                artistID = artistObject.getString("mid");

                                            }
                                        } else {

                                            if (artistObject.has("name")) {

                                                Log.e("ArtistObject: ", "has name");

                                                artist = artist + " ft. " + artistObject.getString("name");

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }


                                    SongInfoModel songInfoModel = new SongInfoModel(123, songTitle,artistID, ((artist == null || (artist.length() == 0)) ? "Unknown" : artist), duration, songData, albumArtURL);
                                    SoundCloudNewSongs.add(songInfoModel);

                                    if (getView() != null){

                                        getView().findViewById(R.id.onlineProgressLoad).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        getView().findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    }



                                }

                            }


                        }
                    }



                newSongsAdapter = new NewSongsAdapter(SoundCloudNewSongs, getContext(),listenerOnline,1);
                recyclerView_newSongs.setAdapter(newSongsAdapter);


            } catch (JSONException e) {


            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            if(error.getMessage()==null)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Timeout error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Timeout error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    songQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.widget.Toast.<init> (Toast.java:114)
  at android.widget.Toast.makeText (Toast.java:277)
  at android.widget.Toast.makeText (Toast.java:267)
  at com.musicplayer.musicana.OnlinePlaySupport$9.onErrorResponse (Unknown Source:15)
  at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError (Unknown Source:8)
  at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run (Unknown Source:62)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6518)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: you can set number of retries using `setRetryPolicy`, but out of memory error is a different issue, post the stack trace

Comment: If you are recommending this solution for second problem, it is okay. But for the first one?

Comment: yes, the solution is for first one, you define the time and number of retries , let me show you

Comment: If the volley request fails the first time then ofcourse the onErrorResponse method will invoked, hence the crash. Right?

Comment: no, the whole purpose of retry is, to try number of times to execute the call successfully

Comment: So why is the OnErrorResponse method called in my code?

Comment: you are using retrypolicy? and if retries are 3 and onerrorresponse is invoked once then it's ideal behavior and also put a check of network connectivity before executing the request, maybe network is not connected at all

Comment: Actually, I'm not using retryPolicy. And the app crashes giving NPE when Toast message is invoked. Why is that?

Comment: can you post the complete logcat details of NPE?

Comment: My app is published actually. I'll post the google console crash report.

Comment: Posted.....please have a look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174095/discussion-between-pavneet-singh-and-sebin-paul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the number of retries to get the successful execution as

```
jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    1000*5, 
    /*DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES*/ 3, 
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
songQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

About NPE. [It is possible that VolleyError is null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40169743/4936904) so you can use

```
if(error!=null && error.getMessage()==null)
```

Comment: 60*1000*5 is for?

Comment: And again, if the request fails, the OnErrorResponse method is called, right?

Comment: bit modification `1000*5` mean five second delay ,  where 1000 is milliseconds and the purpose of retries is to make the request successful with max number of tries

Comment: Ok, so if I got this right it means that request will be send 3 times(each of 5 seconds timeout) until success, right?